# A question on inequality equivalence

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality

I'm doing a textbook question and I'm stuck in the very last end...

I got the following function on $S$:

$$f(S) = S-\frac{q(1-q^S)}{p}+q^Sc$$, where $p:= 1-q$ and $0<p, q<1$.

Now the first forward difference of $f(S)$, so $\Delta(S) := f(S+1)-f(S)$ is

$$\Delta(S) = 1-q^S(pc+q)$$ and this function is increasing in S.

Now I need to find the value of S that satisfies $\Delta(S) \ge 0 $.

We can then write an inequality:

$$q^S \le \frac{1}{(pc+q)}$$

But now when I want to look for $S$, we can take logarithms and find:

$$S \le \frac{-ln(pc+q)}{ln(q)} $$

But the textbook says that the equivalent inequality to $q^S \le \frac{1}{(pc+q)}$ is:

$$S \ge \frac{ln(pc+q)}{-ln(q)} $$

Why is this?

They also say in the question: "using the fact of $ln(q) < 0$".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you divide by a negative number the direction of the inequality get reversed. For example: $5<10$ but when dividing by $-1$ the inequality we have to change the direction: $-5>-10$

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the inequality sign is reversed is because $q<1$, so $\log_q(x)$ is actually a decreasing function. Therefore applying log to both sides will reverse the direction of inequality.